# Aggregate over the maximum timestamp lower than value

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, timestamp, aggregation

So, we trying to aggregate all documents by color,
where for each color, find the maximum timestamp as **max_timestamp**.
Then, filter only buckets where **max_timestamp** is lower then `now-5m`.
The idea here is to check if there is any color without reported document from the last 5 minutes.

Here is what we got by now:

```
{
  "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "colors_aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "color",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_timestamp": {
              "max": {
                "field": "timestamp"
              }
            },
            "aggs": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "timestamp": {
                    "lt": "now-5m"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

It seems to ignore the third aggregation. Buckets with timestamp greater than `now-5m` are shown.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use script to filter-out the unwanted records (in your case records with `timestamp > "now - 5m"`) within the final aggregation, and then your final aggregation (and eventually the output) will be based only on the wanted records. 
The query should be something like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "colors_aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maximals": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timestamp":
          }
        },
        "max_bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "maxs": "max_timestamp"
            },
            "script": {
              "lang": "expression",
              "script": "maxs < [CurrentUnixTime x 1000]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the above script cannot accept the keyword `now-5m` so you will have to set the current unix time every time you execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `max_timestamp` aggregation as a sub-aggregation of the filter one. Try like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "colors_aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "5m": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "timestamp": {
                "lt": "now-5m"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_timestamp": {
              "max": {
                "field": "timestamp"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the `now-5m` filter to apply to the whole aggregation section then you can move it as the top aggregation, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "5m": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "lt": "now-5m"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "colors_aggs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "color",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_timestamp": {
              "max": {
                "field": "timestamp"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I was meant to find colors without any documents from the last 5 min. I should edit my question..

Comment: I want to apply the filter **after** aggregating the maximum timestamp, so I'll get only colors who don't have any records from the last 5 minutes.